# paypal error in codeigniter library

Tags: codeigniter, paypal-sandbox

Fatal error: Call to a member function getMessage() on null in /home/satdevpr/clients.satdevpro.in/lehar/application/libraries/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/common.php on line 119
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function getMessage() on null

Filename: sample/common.php

Line Number: 119

Backtrace:

Comment: What about used code? Care to share?

Comment: You are facing the problem because you sending empty data to common.php that's why getting this error When we click on pay now button it go to payment gateway with the some parameter. Can you show me the url before clicking pay now and after pay now